# Typescript Enums compiling into both d.ts and Javascript output

Tags: javascript, typescript, enums, compilation

In my original TS file (`foo.ts`), I have this:

```
export const enum ACCESS_STATE {
    master,
    readonly,
    none,
    failed
}
```

After the Typescript compiler completes, the output (`foo.d.ts`) file properly contains this:

```
const enum ACCESS_STATE {
    master = 0,
    readonly = 1,
    none = 2,
    failed = 3,
}
```

However, the resulting output (`foo.js`)  file has no reference to `ACCESS_STATE` or its values at all.  This isn't a problem in `foo.js` directly, since the compiler would have properly substituted the `ACCESS_STATE.master` and other references to the hard value of 0 (etc).

The problem is that I have other **javascript** modules that require foo and want to reuse the enum.

Is it possible to have the compiler generate something in the `foo.js` that is referenceable and can be used  ? Such as:

```
var ACCESS_STATE = (function () {
    function ACCESS_STATE () {
        this.master = 0;
        this.readonly = 1;
        this.none = 2;
        this.failed = 3
    }
    return ACCESS_STATE ;
}());
foo.ACCESS_STATE = ACCESS_STATE ;
```

Why is this not the default behavior of the compiler to generate a re-useable kind of thing that can be a referential substitute for the values in the enum (which is what is generally intended by using an enumeration)?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

From the [documentation](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/enums.html#const-enums):

> Const enums can only use constant enum expressions and unlike regular
> enums they are completely removed during compilation.

To have enum code in javascript, you need to remove `const` from `export const enum`. Alternatively,  you can compile your code with `--preserveConstEnums` option.

Comment: I removed the `const` keyword and it worked perfectly for my situation. Thanks for providing both possible solutions.